# MySQL Get difference within same table

Tags: mysql, select

I have this table [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea9211/4/0)

As you can see I am getting 6 rows, now my problem is that I only want unique 4 records with event as group by but instead of getting 1,2,3,4 I want 5,6,3,4 (id)

What I mean is "give me all those unique records where organization id = 0 or 5 but reject organization id 0 records only if it exists in organization id 5"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select max('id'),max(`organization_id`),`title`,`event`,`html_template`,`is_default` 
from templates 
group by `title`,`event`,`html_template`,`is_default`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
SELECT MAX(`id`), MAX(`organization_id`), `title`, `event`, `html_template`, `is_default`
FROM `templates`
GROUP BY `title`, `event`, `html_template`, `is_default`
```

Here is the fiddle:-

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea9211/31